# int not declared in this scope

Tags: programming

This posting contains 2 sketches. the analogmux1 compiles successfully. Concerning analogmuvvolts sketch an error stating updateMux1 was not declared in this scope results. The int Mux1_State [8] = 0: is defined exactly the same in both however the error results.

I'm learning Arduino programming so there are other errors in the sketch. What I'm trying to accomplish is to display the actual voltage of each channel, not numbers which appear in the analogMux.

It would be appreciated if the community could provide me with some guidance.

Analogmux:

```
int pin_Out_S0 = 8;
int pin_Out_S1 = 9;
int pin_Out_S2 = 10;
int pin_In_Mux1 = A0;
int Mux1_State[8] = {0};

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_Out_S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_Out_S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_Out_S2, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(pin_In_Mux1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  updateMux1();
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    if(i == 7) {
      Serial.println(Mux1_State[i]);
    } else {
      Serial.print(Mux1_State[i]);
      Serial.print(",");
    }
  }
}

void updateMux1 () {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S0, HIGH && (i & B00000001));
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S1, HIGH && (i & B00000010));
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S2, HIGH && (i & B00000100));
    Mux1_State[i] = analogRead(pin_In_Mux1);
  }
}
```

And  analogmuxvolts

```
int pin_Out_S0 = 8;
int pin_Out_S1 = 9;
int pin_Out_S2 = 10;
int pin_In_Mux1 = A0;
int Mux1_State[8] = {0};
//float Mux1_State[i] =0;
int RawValue=0;
float Voltage = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_Out_S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_Out_S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_Out_S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_In_Mux1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
 RawValue = analogRead(pin_In_Mux1);
 Voltage = (RawValue * 5.0) / 1024; //scale the ADC
  updateMux1();
  Serial.println(Mux1_State);
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    if(i == 7) {
      Serial.println(Mux1_State[i]);
    } else {
      Serial.print(Mux1_State[i]);
      Serial.print(",");
      //vout = (value * 5.0) / 1024.0;
    }
  }
  Serial.print("Raw  Value = " );
  Serial.print(RawValue); 
}
```

Comment: Is updateMux1() not in the second sketch?

Comment: The error is `updateMux1' was not declared in this scope` and indeed that function is not in the second sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the updateMux() function by copying it from your first sketch into your second sketch:

```
void updateMux1 () {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S0, HIGH && (i & B00000001));
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S1, HIGH && (i & B00000010));
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S2, HIGH && (i & B00000100));
    Mux1_State[i] = analogRead(pin_In_Mux1);
  }
}
```

And do the conversions on the stored Mux1_State[] values during printing like:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    Serial.println(Mux1_State[i]*5.0/1024.0);
    if(i == 7) { 
       Serial.println();
    } else {     
       Serial.print(",");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Dave.    Tom